# Calling a function when the application is in background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, multitasking

In my project I have created a Method which will download the files. When the application is in foreground I can call that download method using the timer

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(download:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

But now I want to call this function when from applicationDidEnterBackground.
If the application is in background how to invoke that download method every 10 or 15 mins ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant simply run the application in the Background in iPhone.Either your application should fell into the audio,voip,location ,external-accessory ,etc category.Please refer this [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3).

Or you have to make the application to come foreground to achieve your tasks.

Go through the apple docs and post your questions

Comment: Thats a nice info you have provided. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KeepAliveTimeout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setKeepAliveTimeout%3ahandler%3a) to get CPU time on every 10 min in BG.

CPU is for very few sec & not guarantee to get exactly at 10 min.

Comment: Thank you , I will check that